# Error: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch class

Tags: trigger, batch, future

My requirement is getting latitude longitude from google map for that i wrote trigger and used @future callouts. now i need to run batch class to update contact records but contacts not updating showing error:

> First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00328000001hmXdAAI; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Geolocation: execution of AfterUpdate
>   caused by: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch apex class

Comment: Your explanation could stand to be expanded on. How does your batch class end up calling an `@future` method? Is it the same `@future` method that is grabbing the lat/long from Google?

Comment: Is that possible to redesign you application to avoid execution batch/future methods from future methods? because last is impossible
Please, post your code -- probably there is a workaround

Comment: Hi user123, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Comment: Can you show your code?  You could potentially be causing the trigger to fire off from your future method which in turn would call the future method again.

Answer (score 22):

The error is straightforward. To work around it, you need to detect when you're already in an @future or batch context, and then simply not call your @future method(s).

Dan Appleman has a pretty good pattern for this, which he presented at one of his sessions at Dreamforce this year. [Defensive Apex Programming](http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/defensive-apex-programming)

Slides 8-10 are the relevant ones here. For the benefit of others, the defensive @future call pattern looks like this

```
public void defensiveFutureCall{
    if(System.isFuture() || System.isBatch()){
        regularSyncCall();
    } else {
        if(Limits.getFutureCalls() < Limits.getLimitFutureCalls()){
            doFutureCall();
        } else {
            // Do some explicit notification so that you know your @future call was denied
        }
    }
}

@future
public void doFutureCall(){
    regularSyncCall();
}

public void regularSyncCall(){
    // Put the code, that you'd otherwise put in your @future method, in here
}
```

Comment: This design pattern....nice!

Answer (score 0):

This is a governor limit provided by salesforce that you cannot call another future method from batch/future method.
But, you can always call a batch process from another batch process.

Thanks